# My Javascript code is not being executed by my browser. The browser just outputs it the way it is written on my text editor

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, text-editor, execute

My browser does not execute my JavaScript code. I want to be able to preview my work in my browser but the browser just outputs the code as I wrote it in the text editor. I am currently learning JavaScript and it is really important that I can test-run my code.

I have tried using different browsers including Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer. Javascript is enabled on all of them. I also tried modifying the settings in my text editor. In Visual Studio code, it seems to be executing in "powershell" and when I tried to open in chrome, it just outputted the code as it was in the text-editor. I have aso tried using Sublime text and Atom but the `result is the same; my Javascript code fails to run but the HTML and CSS run perfectly.`

I expect that when I "run active file" or "view in browser" in Visual Studio Code and Atom respectively, my browser would execute my Javascript code not return the code the way it is on the text editor.

enter code here

```
    function calc() {
        var num1 = prompt("Enter a number");
        var num2 = prompt("Enter another number");
        var sum = Number(num1) + Number(num2);
        alert(sum)};
    calc();

enter code here


    </div>
<script type="text/js" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: @Jlaw33 welcome to the community. It would be great if you can post your code along with the question. Put it in the Code Sample (when you edit the question, look for {} )

Comment: Browsers do not execute JavaScript files directly. They have to be linked as part of a HTML file as shown in the answers below.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially if you're loading your JavaScript from another file you're best to define your function and then call it in a separate script tag (for testing).

One way you can do this is

```html
<html>
  <head>
    
    <script language="javascript">
      /* 
        Replace this script block with
        <script language="javascript" src="myscript.js">
        inside your HTML file as i'm simply using this 
        block as an example of what your actual external 
        script would contain.
      */
      function calc() {
        var one = Number( prompt("Enter #1: ") );
        var two = Number( prompt("Enter #2: ") );
        alert( one + two )
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script language="javascript">
        calc();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Make sure that the function you're referencing has been loaded before you call it. By this I mean you are best to always put your `<script src="" />` tags in the `<head>` of your HTML while learning javascript.

I Hope this helps :)

Comment: Yes I made use of the script tags although the script is a separate file so I referenced it in the HTML with the 'src' attribute. But the issue is not only present when the script is part of a web page, even my independent JavaScript code fails to execute.

Comment: Are you able to attach your script

Comment: I just attached some of my code; but it doesn't seem to be a problem of linking the files because few days ago the code was executing perfectly, including the javascript but now the javascript code, no matter how simple is not executed but is just reproduced in the browser. I would have added some pictures of the browser output but I am a new member and I am not yet qualified to embed images in my questions.

Answer (score 0):

A script needs to be referenced within an html page.
So assuming your JS file is written inside `my-script.js`, create a new html file `my-page.html` and save it at the same level as the js file.
Contents of my-page.html should be:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
   </head>
   <body>

   <script src="my-script.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```